# How to pass this variable to this function?

Tags: javascript

I have to pass **aaa** to **ehi()** function in the **mitt** parameter.

**aaa** is an array of numbers like: 29837,127365,5645,12323,47656564,2312,4534,2343

This is the correct way that the **ehi()** works:

```
   function ehi(aaa) {
      love({functionality: 'kiss',
            mess: 'yuhuuuuuu',
            mitt: '29837,127365,5645,12323,47656564,2312,4534,2343'
      });
   }
```

I need to substitute 29837,127365,5645,12323,47656564,2312,4534,2343 with aaa.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array`'s has a [`join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) which calls the `toString()` of each element and concatates them with the joiner specified.

```
love({functionality: 'kiss',
      mess: 'yuhuuuuuu',
      mitt: aaa.join(",")
});
```

Comment: i think "delimiter" is the word you were looking for :D good answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is not clear enough, does your `mitt` need a string or an array?

If `aaa` already is a real array ( `aaa = [...] // typeof(aaa) === "object"` ) and `mitt` needs a String, then take the following:

```
mitt: aaa.join(',')
```

if your mitt needs an Array simply do:

```
mitt: aaa
```

However, if `aaa` is a string, do the either:

```
mitt: aaa.split(',') //<- passes an array to mitt
```

or

```
mitt: aaa // <- passes aaa as a string to mitt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
love({functionality: 'kiss',
        mess: 'yuhuuuuuu',
        mitt: aaa.join(',')
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
 love({functionality: 'kiss',
        mess: 'yuhuuuuuu',
        mitt: aaa
  });
```